# Generating Fortify report in maven

Tags: maven, plugins

I am trying to generate a fortify report using maven, I have downloaded the plug-in Fortify360, and fortify-plugin-1.0, installed it in my repository and then added the dependencies in my profile, But i am not able to generate a fortify report(.fpr)file of my java source code.Can you please help me with how can i do it??

Answer (score 6):

Fortify provides source code for maven plugin. You need to build it

Step # 1 Build fortify plugin

Open command prompt

```
cd %FORTIFY_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY%\HP_FORTIFY\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.90\Samples\advanced\maven-plugin

mvn clean install
```

After sucessful build fortify plugin will be present into your local repository

Step # 2 Add fortify source code analyzer dependency to your project pom file

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.90</version>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
```

Note - Make sure you verify fortify scan plugin version

```
FORTIFY_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY%\HP_FORTIFY\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.90\Samples\advanced\maven-plugin\pom.xml
```

Step # 3 Create .frp / report file

```
mvn sca:translate
mvn sca:scan
```

This will generate fortify scan report file in the target directory

Comment: From where can i download the source code to build?

Answer (score 0):

Use maven-sca-plugin, and execute the following command.

```
mvn sca:scan
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single-module project:

```
mvn clean
mvn sca:clean
mvn install sca:translate
mvn -Dfortify.sca.Xmx=800M sca:scan
```