# maven fortify plugin : Unable to load build session with ID XXXXX .. See log file for more details

Tags: plugins, fortify

I took refrence from  : [Generating Fortify report in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752483/generating-fortify-report-in-maven/18864707#18864707)

but invoking : mvn sca:scan

throws below error :

Unable to load build session with ID XXXXX .. See log file for more details.
[ERROR] Error invoking sourceanalyzer. Exit code: 1.
Verify your project settings and your SCA installation.

I tried looking around various posts , but no luck.

Could someone please advise.

Comment: This requires setting up JVM heapsize while translation and scan . This fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly running "mvn sca:scan" will not work.
The following needs to be executed before "mvn sca:scan""

mvn sca:translate